# How to know if MySQL returns 0

Tags: php, mysql

When I run this query `

> SELECT `id` FROM `bckoff` WHERE `left`
>   = 3;

`
in phpmyAdmin, I get the correct response

> MySQL returned an empty result set
>   (i.e. zero rows).

However, when I run the same query through my PHP code using mysql_query('the above query').. then I get `"Resource ID#5"` or `"Resource ID#6"` and so on..

How do I get the empty result set (or zero rows) in PHP ?

Comment: Depends on what mySQL library you are using in PHP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[mysql_num_rows](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) is the answer. This function returns the number of rows affected by a executed query.

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM bckoff WHERE left  = 3";

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo mysql_num_rows($result);
```

When you execute `mysql_query($query)` it executes the query and puts it in a resource. This resource can be read by different mysql-functions (like mysql_num_rows). For a complete overview of all MySQL functions have a look at http://nl.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php

*Note: Extension used in above code is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, Use  MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension.*
So instead of mysql_num_rows use **mysqli_num_rows()**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function as:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM bckoff WHERE left = 3");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
// $num_rows will be 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mysql_fetch_* function to retrieve the results. Look here

[Mysql Fetch Functions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `mysql_num_rows` function that you can call on the `$result` returned by `mysql_query("SELECT ...")`.

You might look into the MySQLi extension instead. It's a big improvement over the MySQL driver, and allows you to use prepared statements and bind parameters among other things, and I find it much more comfortable to use. You can look at the examples on the [documentation page for `num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).